# Why can't I use Promise in node v0.11.11?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm just messing around with the `v0.11` branch of node, and I'm wondering why I can't use the native ES6 `Promise` object, even with `--harmony` turned on.

My normal chrome browsers:

```
Google Chrome    32.0.1700.77 (Official Build 244503) 
JavaScript       V8 3.22.24.10
```

Supports them, and node.js `v0.11.11` is telling me:

```
> process.versions.v8
'3.22.24.19'
```

So what gives?

Comment: Promises currently in Chrome are DOM Futures. Also, they're very experimental and the API might change (it's quite heavily discussed atm). Consider using [Bluebird promise instead as they're faster, have better stack traces and stable](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

Comment: So basically because it's a DOM api and not a javascript API.

Comment: @mpm there _are_ promises in ES6, they're just not 'settled' yet - the Chrome people are quite angry too : http://esdiscuss.org/topic/promise-cast-and-promise-resolve#content-77

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum -- Well that explains why node doesn't have them, but why are they considered part of the DOM???  I've been using `q` forever, this isn't an issue of me wanting to find a library, just curious why it didn't work.  If you post an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Native Promises are in, you can now use them. They're still slower and harder to debug than libraries like Bluebird but they're there.

---

Promises currently in Chrome are DOM Futures. Also, they're very experimental and the API might change (it's quite heavily discussed atm).

Consider using [Bluebird promise instead as they're faster, have better stack traces and are stable](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

It is consdierably faster than libraries like `Q` (two orders of magnitude faster) it has much better stack traces and a completely spec compliant API. You may of course also compile node and v8 yourself - there are [promises in v8 itself](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/promise.js).

There are promises in ES6, they're just not 'settled' yet - [making the Chrome people are quite angry too](http://esdiscuss.org/topic/promise-cast-and-promise-resolve#content-77)

They're considered part of the DOM too because future DOM APIs will use promises.

Comment: Note: If you do compile Node and V8 yourself note that those promises include debated methods like `.chain` (a non unwrapping then) that may or may not make it into the standard.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)  Happen to have references to when Promises will be incorporated into v8?

Comment: @zyklus the truth is, there is quite the argument about them right now. People are working hard but I believe that not for the next few months. I think your best bet is something like Bluebird that is as fast as native and supports the same API.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting a new project.  Vaguely considering polyfilling `bluebird` onto `global.Promise` then removing it with node `v0.12` or whenever Promises get incorporated

Comment: @zyklus in all honesty - chances are Bluebird will still be faster and consume less memory than native promises - but yes. If you restrict yourself to only use standard methods you can easily swap it out - the library is extensively tested against the standard.

Comment: @zyklus, ES6 promises have been in V8 proper since version 3.23.14 (28 Nov 2013). But node still has to catch up.