# How to use promise in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-harmony

So, I have an nodejs with promises support:

```
$ node -v
v0.11.11
```

But when I try to use Promises I have an error:

```
$ node --harmony test.js
require, module, __filename, __dirname) {         var promise = new Promise(fu
                                                                ^
ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/just-boris/coding/test.js:1:89)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
    at startup (node.js:123:16)
    at node.js:1128:3
```

source code in [my gist](https://gist.github.com/just-boris/9503046)

What I am doing wrong? Moreover, I try to run [generators example](https://gist.github.com/creationix/5544019) and it's working, so it means that es6 features are enabled except promises

Comment: Check for similar questions before asking a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754032/why-cant-i-use-promise-in-node-v0-11-11

Comment: Thanks! I search this question like that, but can't find.
Have voted up to it, maybe it helps anybody

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promises have only landed in V8 a few months ago (in October, IIRC). The version of node you are running is behind that version of V8.

Edit: Correction, first version landed end of November, in what became V8 3.23.14.

Comment: @user568109 I love how you say that so confidently to Andreas who you clearly didn't bother checking out - especially since Andreas is a TC39 member and a Google engineer working on V8. Here - https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/promise.js , the only thing he got wrong is the October date since v8 had promises (not to mention Mark Miller's experiments in v8) for longer. That doesn't change the answer on the other question though (which is similar but different).

Comment: @Benjamin Oops, I just read your answer. I had used promises in Chrome before but could not use it in node. This led me to think they are Chrome specific. I did not check this situation till now. Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, and I actually implemented V8 promises ;-). I just checked, first version landed Nov 27 (which should have become V8 3.23.14).

Comment: @AndreasRossberg thanks for answer, I'll be looking forward V8 update in node.js

Comment: @Benjamin I was surprised at first that Chrome had its own promises. I checked the Chrome-dev mails/threads which mentioned this. V8 did not have promises then and many harmony features were missing in V8.

Comment: @user568109, the history is that promises first came up in the DOM, and were only adopted by ES later (mid last year). That's why they appeared in Blink first (current Chrome still uses the Blink version, but we are in the process of migrating over).

Comment: Yes, That is what I had in my mind. Anyways promises will happen now. My apologies for the confusion. Thanks for clearing it up. +1